# Are my firebase cloud functions exploitable?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Before I work any deeper into my project, I'd like to know if my project is secure. I have several cloud functions that change database values based on `context.auth.uid`. For example...

```
exports.sendFCMToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>{

    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const fcmToken = data.fcm_token

    return admin.database().ref('/users/user_token/' + uid + '/token/value').set(fcmToken);

});
```

I call the function from my app

```
private Task<Object> sendFCMToken(final String token){

    Map<String, Object> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
    itemMap.put("fcm_token", token);

    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("sendFCMToken")
            .call(itemMap)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    return (Object) task.getResult().getData();
                }
            });

}
```

I am just wondering if this is a secure way, or can this request be spoofed?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Everybody can call your cloud function, you have to write your security inside your cloud function. Don't forget when you query with admin (admin.database()...) rules are ignored. Take care of that.

Comment: I know there's no rules, but I was just wondering if the uid could be spoofed to make it look like another user is sending the request.

Comment: You'll need to include the user's ID token in the request. Check out [this documentation on ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) regarding getting and then verifying the token... sounds like that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank jeremy. If i'm not mistaken, this is for a custom backend which is what im not using. The context in the cloud function should contain the id token which contains the uid right?

Comment: Ahhh, after reading the docs in more depth I see where you could think that... the first sentence on the link I provided even suggests that. Without making a sample app to log and inspect the context I can't confirm/deny whether it contains the ID token. If it does - great. If not, then your front end needs to explicitly get and send the token along with the request. Check out [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) and read the section titled "ID Token Verification" where it explains that the ID tokens are for customizing your backend - i.e. the server side cloud functions

Comment: I was hoping someone could confirm I was calling cloud functions securely. If changing database values is secure with a conditional uid rule - "if ($uid == auth.uid)", then I'm sure the way I'm doing it will be fine. Not that I think anyone would try to exploit my project in the first place anyway. No worries. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The admin SDK bypasses the database security rules (_as Curse mentioned in the first comment_), so using `$uid == auth.uid` by itself is not secure... or at least, it doesn't secure the db from malicious users exploiting an unsecured cloud function. In the code you provided you aren't using a database trigger for your cloud function - but if that's what you're talking about changing it to - then yes that would be a safe way to trigger the function since the user would have to pass the `$uid == auth.uid` to change the value in the first place, before the function is called.